# How to handle concurrent requests with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have problem with EventEmitter memory leak detected

I have function that starts the browser like this

```
async function startBrowser() {
const revisionInfo = await browserFetcher.download("901912");
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: revisionInfo.executablePath,
    args: [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--no-first-run",
      "--no-zygote",
      "--single-process",
    ],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  return { browser, page };
}
```

One of my functions maps through number of items like

```
const work = (stuff) => {
    const workTodo = stuff.map(item = {
     setTimeout(() => {
      anotherFunction(some params)
     }, some time variable all different seconds
     }
     await Promise.all(workTodo);


}
```

and in the anotherFunction()

```
    anotherFunction(someParams) {
    const { browser, page } = await startBrowser();
    try {
    await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('stuff');
    await page.waitForSelector('stuff');
    await page.click('stuff');

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();

   } catch (error) {
     console.log('error', error);
    return 
   }
```

The logic in anotherFunction() works about 70-80 % of the time, but sometimes it gets timeout exceeded at waitForSelector calls and sometimes I get memory leak errors.

Am I creating too many browsers ? and not closing properly?

Can someone who knows puppeteer tell me what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Your browser doesn't get closed in the last `catch`, maybe that's it.

Comment: what do you mean by catch?

Comment: Close the browser in a `finally` block. pguardiario is pointing out that when your code throws, the cleanup logic at the end of the `try` block is skipped. Using `finally` ensures that regardless of whether it throws or not, you're guaranteed no leak.